# How to randomly pick colors and shapes from a for loop and display it in another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

Here is my code:

http://jsbin.com/tecomodanu/edit?html,css,js,output

I'm trying to create a reactions game where the program displays a certain shape and color from the top which the player would select the same criteria from those in the 9 boxes and their timing counted. But I'm not sure how to get it from one of those 9 shapes and display it. Still a newbie at javascript. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you say get it from one of those 9 shapes, do you mean the box at the top?

Comment: Like the game displays a certain shape at the top from the "Click on a:" and the player has to match it to those shapes in the 9 boxes.

Comment: Are you having trouble getting a new random shape after each user click?

Comment: Yeah, I'm also trying to match the shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code abit.

So basically what I did was to save the 'Correct' Answer into a variable. Then set this 'Answer' into 1 of the 9 boxes. Then I added a class called 'answer' so that when the user click that color you can identify and you can do the reaction time calculation.

http://jsbin.com/xigonariza/edit?html,css,js,console,output

The code is just a raw and you should optimize abit.